# ActionResult is never invoked in ASP.NET MVC / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crud

I need to update the price of a particular product in my ASP.NET MVC application connected to a local database.

The `ProductController` is the following, which should update the content of the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePrice(Models.Product product)
{
    string query = "UPDATE product SET price=@price  WHERE productId=@idproduct";
      
    string constr = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=accounting;persistsecurityinfo=True";

    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproduct", product.idproduct);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", product.price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", product.name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", product.description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", product.cost);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", product.quantity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", product.sku);

            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(product.price);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This is the view of the product, that in the same file shows all the products and allow a user to edit the price of the product by using Javascript

```
<table class="table" id="tblProducts">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
        </th>
       
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </th>
       
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="Product Name">
                <span>@item.name</span>
                
            </td>
            <td class="Description">
                <span>@item.description</span>
               
            </td>
            <td class="Price">
                <span>@item.price</span>
                <input type="text" value="@item.price" style="display:none; width: 50px;" />
            </td>

            <td>
                <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;"  " >Edit</a>
                <a class="Update" href="javascript:;"  "style="display:none">Update</a>
                <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>
                
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Edit event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#tblProducts .Edit", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    $(this).find("input").show();
                    $(this).find("span").hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Update").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").show();
            row.find(".Delete").hide();
            $(this).hide();
        });
        //Update event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#tblProducts .Update", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    var span = $(this).find("span");
                    var input = $(this).find("input");
                    span.html(input.val());
                    span.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Delete").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").hide();
            $(this).hide();

            var product = {};
            //product.idproduct= row.find(".productId").find("span").html();
            //product.name = row.find(".Product Name").find("span").html();
            product.price = row.find(".Price").find("span").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Product/UpdatePrice",
                data: '{product:' + JSON.stringify(product) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
 </script>
```

The problem I am having is that the price is updated in the html page, and I can see the changes, but no changes are actually applied to the database, looking at it I can only see updates if I actually update manually the database from MySql Workbench. Any suggestion on what I should do? I have put breakpoints in Visual Studio and it seems that the price is changed in the Product model, but nothing is updated in the database.

Comment: So are you saying that the database isn't updated via the code you provided, or that the `UpdatePrice` method is never called? Your 'ajax` isn't posting the proper endpoint, you have it pointing to `/Product/Index` not `Product/UpdatePrice`

Comment: Try wrapping your mysql command in a try/catch block to see if there are errors from the database.

Comment: @LasSincas Your Ajax is flawed, the url is pointing to `Index` of Product controller not `UpdatePrice`, try changing your Ajax url property to `/Product/UpdatePrice` You can also add the `success` and `error` callbacks to your Ajax so that you can catch errors and process UI changes on `success`

Comment: Maybe the route is invalid - can you specify the route explicitly? as a function attribute [Route("api/UpdatePrice")]
also try [FromBody] as a parameter attribute

Comment: @RyanWilson Changing the ajax endpoint to /Product/UpdatePrice lets me call the ActionResult, but the database value price of Product never changes. The price is changed in the html page, but as soon as I refresh it goes back to the standard value, and the database has no changes

Comment: You don't supply the `@idproduct` parameter value it's commented out.

Comment: @Max yep, sorry I had forgot that, I have updated that bit in the question

Comment: @LasSincas My bad. I forgot you had it hard coded in a string, you can remove your comment. If all you are passing in is the price and product id, why are you setting all those other parameters? Have you checked the value of the price and the id being passed to the controller and checked those against what you are seeing in the DB?

Comment: @RyanWilson NP. I have tried to pass all the parameters to see if there was any difference. How would you do that? I have put breakpoints in VS to see if the price was changed, and it is changed, but still nothing happens to DB. When I get to the "return" bit it shows the new correct price, but DB in Workbench and in Server Explorer are not updated

Comment: @LasSincas I imagine you have some kind of DB software you can query the table with, so do a query against the database and see what the id and price is before you get to your sql call, set a break point inside your controller method and inspect your model to see what the value of the product id and price is.

Comment: @RyanWilson I have another question, which might get us somewhere: When I set the breakpoint and I get all the values of the Model the only thing that is updated is the price, and then I can see that the other properties are all null or 0(for int) while they should have their original values. Might be that and indicator of failure?

Comment: @LasSincas If the product id of your model is 0 then that explains why your query is failing to update. It can't update something with an id that doesn't exist. From looking at your HTML and your product object you are passing in your Ajax, I don't see anywhere where you set a product id, so that is why it is failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238998/discussion-between-las-sincas-and-ryan-wilson).

Comment: @LasSincas Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, put the product id into a hidden input, so you can pass it to the controller when you post:

```
...

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="Product Name">
            <span>@item.name</span>               
        </td>
        <td class="Description">
            <span>@item.description</span>               
        </td>
        <td class="Price">
            <span>@item.price</span>
            <input type="text" value="@item.price" style="display:none; width: 50px;" />
        </td>

        <td>
            @*Adding a hidden input with the product id on next line*@
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.idproduct" style="display:none;" class="hdn-product-id" />
            <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;"  " >Edit</a>
            <a class="Update" href="javascript:;"  "style="display:none">Update</a>
            <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>                
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now you can grab the product's id when the update button is pressed, I also added `success` and `error` callbacks for your Ajax:

```
    //Update event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#tblProducts .Update", function () {
        const row = $(this).closest("tr");
        //now we can get the product id to pass to the controller
        const prodid = $(this).closest('td').find('.hdn-product-id').val();
        
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find("span");
                var input = $(this).find("input");
                span.html(input.val());
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        row.find(".Delete").show();
        row.find(".Cancel").hide();
        $(this).hide();

        var product = {};
        
        product.price = row.find(".Price").find("span").html();
        //set the id to the model
        product.idproduct = prodid;
         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Product/UpdatePrice",
            data: '{product:' + JSON.stringify(product) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                //do something on success of post
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception){
               //do something on error
            }
        });
    });
```

Now when your Post method occurs, you should have the id of the product to update and your query will behave as expected.